# `DT[, function(.SD), by = ID]` behaves differently from `function(DT[ID %in% ID_GROUP])`

Tags: r, data.table

I am working with Geolife Trajectories 1.3 dataset (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=52367).
It contains bunch of folders, where each folder is separate user.
Each user have few separate .plt files with GPS coord and DATE-TIME info.
Some users have file with labels - time intervals, and transportation type
taken by user (airplane, car, etc)

I created two datasets, first contain all users ID's, DATE-TIMES's and other
info, irrelevant for now:

```
first dataset with users ID's and DATE's:
ID      DATE
20      2007-04-29 08:34:32
...     ...
100     2007-04-29 12:35:04
```

second contains all user ID's, StartTIME's, EndTime's and Transportation type:

```
   ID          Start.Time            End.Time Transportation
1: 21 2007/04/29 12:34:24 2007/04/29 12:53:45           taxi
2: 21 2007/04/29 22:27:11 2007/04/30 04:28:00           car
...
```

From 'StartTIME, EndTime' columns of second dataset I created dataset with lubridate intervals:

```
2007-04-29 12:34:24 UTC--2007-04-29 12:53:45 UTC
...
2007-04-29 22:27:11 UTC--2007-04-30 04:28:00 UTC
```

Than I wrote 2 functions:

```
# function for single row label processing
#   will search row's DATE in a subset of intervals for current ID
#   if TRUE - will search for a label in a subset of labels for current ID
get_label <- function(id, date, labels_subset, interval_subset) {
    # convert date to POSIX time
    single_time <- as.POSIXct(date)
    # search for current time in intervals subset and get label
    result <- labels_subset[single_time %within% interval_subset]$Transportation
    # check for result, if there is none -> return NA
    if (identical(as.vector(result), character(0))) {
        # "is type 'character' but expecting type 'logical'. Column types must be
        # consistent for each group." will raise if `return(NA)` without `as.char`
        return(as.character(NA))
    } else {
        return(as.character(result))
    }
}
```

and

```
# function for ID subset label processing
#   will create a subset of intervals for current ID
#   will create a subset of labels for current ID   
get_group <- function(tab) {
    # grep ID
    id <- tab$ID[1]
    # create interval subset for ID
    interval_subset <- intervals[labels_d$ID == id]
    # create label subset for ID
    labels_subset <- labels_d[labels_d$ID == id]
    # pass all data for get_label function -- process `tab` by row
    tab[, get_label(as.integer(ID), as.character(DATE), labels_subset, interval_subset), 1:nrow(tab)]
}
```

I want to get a vector with lables if DATE are in some lubridate interval and
NA if it is not in any lubridate interval for current ID.

And `tmp <- get_group(dt[ID %in% c(21, 110)])` works:

```
> unique(tmp$V1)
[1] NA     "car"  "walk"
```

But `tmp <- dt[, get_group(.SD), by = ID]` does not work properly, it outputs only NA's (and dt have only two ID's -- 21 and 110):

```
> unique(tmp$V1)
[1] NA
```

Even if I create DT with only one ID, `function(DT)` works and `DT[,function(.SD), by = ID]` does not:

```
tmp<- DT[ID==21]

unique(tmp[, get_group(.SD), by = ID]$V1)
>[1] NA

unique(get_group(tmp)$V1)
>[1] NA     "car"  "walk"
```

Why, what I am doing wrong?

**UPD:** 
I should have printed `.SD` earlier.
By default, R does not pass `by=` argument into `.SD`, so my function could not achieve an `ID`. Sadly, there is no standard warning about that.
`.SDcols` did the trick:

```
tmp[, get_group(.SD), by = ID, .SDcols=c('ID', 'DATE')]
```

Comment: are you trying to join the 2 datasets such that DATE from dataset1 is between Start.Time and End.Time of dataset2?

Comment: @chinsoon12 Yes, your description is short and more understandable than my somewhat bloated text) Is there is a better way to do such thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a data.table non-equi join as follows:

```
ds2[ds1, on=.(ID, Start.Time <= DATE, End.Time >= DATE)]
```